# Converting a gradient with 13 steps to a gradient of 8 steps?

Tags: gradient

I have the following gradient with 13 steps:

[image]

This is the output of https://cssgradient.io/ I used to create it:

```
background: rgb(52,17,46);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(52,17,46,1) 0%, rgba(111,31,71,1) 8%, rgba(140,46,144,1) 17%, rgba(110,84,199,1) 25%, rgba(77,137,187,1) 33%, rgba(69,173,136,1) 42%, rgba(71,195,61,1) 50%, rgba(181,218,48,1) 58%, rgba(240,134,32,1) 67%, rgba(255,193,44,1) 75%, rgba(255,215,107,1) 83%, rgba(255,234,170,1) 92%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
```

Now I need to use that in my Unity game, the thing is, their gradient object only accepts 8 steps.

**Question:**

How can I convert this 13 steps gradient to a gradient with 8 steps?

(any tool or tutorial would be appreciated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any graphics design or image editing software to do this - I'll choose Illustrator in this case.

You have several gradient stops which are there to preserve subtleties of transition, and several which appear truly superfluous - I'll mark those out with a red "X" and try removing them - I'll alter the spacing od the gradient around the removals to visually compensate and see how close we can get.

13 stops per post
[image]

Marked "X" for removal
[image]

8 stops gradient - not a *perfect* match, but pretty darn close.
[image]

I think you can safely eliminate the stops I did and tweak a bit inside Unity in the Shader graph and get what you need done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping for a tool that'd magically do that but I guess I'm asking for the impossible ... anyway, thanks !

Comment: Trouble with automated tools is that to get a smooth *perceptual* gradation fitting the human visual system takes a pretty advanced AI, and though these sorts of things are indeed in development and often get included into tools like Photoshop, at the time of writing, I'm unaware of one which does this anything like as well as the human eye and training.

Comment: Makes sense, I think I'm just going to copy and paste what you've done on your screenshots because I only ever have this gradient to convert. And graphic design is a topic I am not exactly versed in :)

Comment: You always have the workaround of converting your proposed gradient into a texture... depends on what you’re using it for in Unity.

Comment: That's right, I thought about that but since now I have my shiny shader that leverages Unity gradient, I couldn't simply not use it :) By the way, take a look at the output of a very basic program I've just crafted to try automate this conversion: https://ibb.co/878hcnK suprisingly (IMO) albeit not as faithful, the end result looks perceptually smoother! Anyway, that's a never ending debate when it comes to colors :D

Comment: Awesome! You gonna leave that up? I could use that too - same issue, btw - also Unity endpoint!

Comment: Well you know what, I've simply dropped the idea because such gradient looks dull against a background like PS one ... :) So I've reverted to a simple yet very clear single color bar though I might go your last way again (texture) (btw if you have an idea on how I could make it look it nice against a #1F1F1F background you're welcome) Here's the WPF app, it does not make any assumption, just parses colors then samples the the gradient (then you are supposed to grab a PNG out of it) should be trivial to improve https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AdJndQ3RnWLvP2u3udRtFdzW8LZMtCZY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: By the way, there appears to be a small bug in the ColorHelper.Evaluate when first and last stop are not 0 and 1 (seen that on my shader but didn't fix it), should be trivial to fix the for each loops. And almost forgot, here's the UI gradient shader I've posted at forum https://forum.unity.com/threads/wiki-drawing-an-ui-element-using-unityengine-gradient.658120/

Comment: Here's how my gradient looks like currently against a dark background: https://ibb.co/0hcMGMz I am more less trying to do like this: https://ibb.co/z8HGg5C but obviously when you don't know about graphic design there really isn't much you can do about improving it (simply don't know what to do)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92213/discussion-between-gerardfalla-and-aybe).